# python kafka can not commit a message

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-python

I created a new topic, and wrote a function to consume messages:

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer(topic, bootstrap_servers=broker_list, auto_offset_reset='earliest', group_id='test', enable_auto_commit=True)
for msg in consumer:
    print(msg.value)
    time.sleep(1)
```

I use the following function to check the committed status of each partition:

```
def get_current_offset(topic, group):

    consumer = KafkaConsumer(
            bootstrap_servers=broker_list,
            group_id=group,
            enable_auto_commit=False
        )   

    for p in consumer.partitions_for_topic(topic):
        tp = TopicPartition(topic, p)
        consumer.assign([tp])
        committed = consumer.committed(tp)
        consumer.seek_to_end(tp)
        last_offset = consumer.position(tp)

        if not committed:
            committed = 0 
        print("topic: %s partition: %s committed: %s last: %s lag: %s" % (topic, p, committed, last_offset, (last_offset - committed)))

    consumer.close(autocommit=False)
```

The problem is whenever I consume a message, the output of `get_current_offset` is:

```
topic: zhihu_comment partition: 0 committed: 0 last: 29199 lag: 29199
topic: zhihu_comment partition: 1 committed: 0 last: 29089 lag: 29089
topic: zhihu_comment partition: 2 committed: 0 last: 29149 lag: 29149
```

which indicates that there were no messages committed. What I feel weird is that another topic, consumed the same way, can commit normally.

```
topic: zhihu_profile partition: 0 committed: 699879 last: 699879 lag: 0
topic: zhihu_profile partition: 1 committed: 697061 last: 697061 lag: 0
topic: zhihu_profile partition: 2 committed: 697127 last: 697127 lag: 0
```

Is there anything wrong with the topic?

#### Update:

I tried to use `kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server device1:9092 --topic zhihu_comment --group test --from-beginning`
to consume, and messages are committed normally!

So, I suspect it's because of a problem with `kafka-python`.